# Prevent CompileAssemblyFromSource from generate temp files with duplicate file name

Tags: c#, wcf, compileassemblyfromsource

My WCF application uses code compiled in run time to calculate some values of a report. I'm using CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource to compile the code.
If the client (a Silverlight application) request a report while another report is being calculated the CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource generates temp files with duplicated name, what lead to a IOException ("The file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\uviewdyd.out' already exists.")

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: This seems to be a very old question, I to have a similar problem. Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. It looks like all three variants (file, DOM and source) create temp files ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/csharp/csharpcodeprovider.cs,54aabf6119efbd8e)).
The best way seems to use different temp paths for each compilation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37136996/5682035:

```cs
CSharpCodeProvider prov = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters();
parms.TempFiles = new TempFileCollection(tempdir);
```